# How to get the data in between two diffrence classes from Mysql database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to get the data from two classes. For example if I select from class '1' and to class '3', I need to get the data in between 1 to 3 classes.

My DB(tbl_timetable) like this :

```
ID  From_class  To_class timetable pageno
---------------------------------------------
1    1            4        text      1,2
--------------------------------------------
2    2            5         data     3,4
-------------------------------------------
3    4            7        somedata
```

If I select fromclass 1 and toclass 6 from Listbox, I need to get the data from all 3 rows. Please help me how to write mysql query for that one.

My Form will be like this

```
   <b>School</b><b>:</b>
<select name="school_id" id="school_id" class="list_box">
<option value="select">Select School</option>
<?php
$school_sql=mysql_query("select * from tbl_school");
while($school=mysql_fetch_array($school_sql))
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $school['school_id'];?>" <?php if(isset($_GET['school_id']) && ($_GET['school_id']==$school['school_id'])) { echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> ><?php echo $school['school_name'];?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>

<b>From Class</b><b>:</b>
<select name="from_class" id="from_class" class="list_box">
<option name="select" value="select">Select Class</option>
<option name="1"  value="1" <?php if($_GET['from_class']=='1') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?> >1</option>
<option name="2"  value="2" <?php if($_GET['from_class']=='2') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>2</option>
<option name="3"  value="3" <?php if($_GET['from_class']=='3') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>3</option>
<option name="4"  value="4" <?php if($_GET['from_class']=='4') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>4</option>
<option name="5"  value="5" <?php if($_GET['from_class']=='5') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>5</option>
<option name="6"  value="6" <?php if($_GET['from_class']=='6') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>6</option>
<option name="7"  value="7" <?php if($_GET['from_class']=='7') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>7</option>
<option name="8"  value="8" <?php if($_GET['from_class']=='8') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>8</option>
<option name="9"  value="9" <?php if($_GET['from_class']=='9') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>9</option>
<option name="10" value="10" <?php if($_GET['from_class']=='10') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>10</option>
<option name="11" value="11" <?php if($_GET['from_class']=='11') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>11</option>
<option name="12" value="12" <?php if($_GET['from_class']=='12') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>12</option>
</select>

<b>To Class</b><b>:</b>

<select name="to_class" id="to_class" class="list_box">
<option name="select" value="">Select Class</option>
<option name="1"  value="1" <?php if($_GET['to_class']=='1') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>1</option>
<option name="2"  value="2" <?php if($_GET['to_class']=='2') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>2</option>
<option name="3"  value="3" <?php if($_GET['to_class']=='3') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>3</option>
<option name="4"  value="4" <?php if($_GET['to_class']=='4') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>4</option>
<option name="5"  value="5" <?php if($_GET['to_class']=='5') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>5</option>
<option name="6"  value="6" <?php if($_GET['to_class']=='6') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>6</option>
<option name="7"  value="7" <?php if($_GET['to_class']=='7') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>7</option>
<option name="8"  value="8" <?php if($_GET['to_class']=='8') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>8</option>
<option name="9"  value="9" <?php if($_GET['to_class']=='9') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>9</option>
<option name="10" value="10" <?php if($_GET['to_class']=='10') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>10</option>
<option name="11" value="11" <?php if($_GET['to_class']=='11') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>11</option>
<option name="12" value="12" <?php if($_GET['to_class']=='12') echo "Selected='selected'"; ?>>12</option>
</select>
```

My output need to display Timetable and Pageno ofs selected Classes.

Answer (score 0):

try  this one:

```
select * from tbl_timetable where From_class between  "From_class value" and "to_class value";
```